# Using multiples storages and task hubs for orchestrators between same function app in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions, orchestration

I'm working with durable clients and I can't find the way to have multiple task hubs for each orchestrator in the same function app. Is this possible, and if so, how?
Can I also have, between the same function app, multiple orchestrators using different storages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, a `Function App` can only have one `task hub`, and orchestrators in a function app should use the same storage.

The following two designs are allowed:

[image]

Please refer to this [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-task-hubs?tabs=csharp).